# Move folder in git

Tags: windows, git, directory

I'm new to git. I use Windows, and github & bitbucket.
I set up my git repositories in the folder C:\Users\MyUserName.ssh
because I thought I had to.

Now I realize it's better if I have these repositories in dropbox instead. I'm assuming that cutting and pasting a folder (repository) from C:\Users\MyUserName.ssh to my dropbox folder might cause some harm .. like maybe GIT PULL will no longer know where to bring the files to.

What's the best way to move the folder ?

Comment: You can move the folder where ever you want - the git metadata is contained within the checkout folder.

Comment: I originally thought that it had to be in the .ssh folder. I have not tried it because I was afraid I would damage something (I'm completely new). So is the .ssh folder just for storing the three files: id_rsa, id_rsa.pub , and known_hosts ? The git repositories don't have to be there ? And if I originally set up my git repositories in there, I can move them somewhere else and continue using git *exactly* like I used to ?

Comment: Yes, git doesn't care where the repository is as long as the .git directory in the repository root comes along with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the folder is located on the file system. Just move the folder and go ahead and pull.